# Magento 2.3.3 - Catalog price rule and tax

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

can anyone hint me, how I can let the Catalog Price rules be applied including tax. Means, when we set up a voucher in the system, that the discount of the voucher is taken into account incl. tax already.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You probably use Cart Rules not Catalog Rules (only Cart Rules can have coupons).

Under `System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Settings > Apply Customer Tax` there is  an option for the order tax rules which can be either `Before Discount` or `After Discount`.

Have you tried this?

Then you can set Order Totals sort order described in this doc: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-totals-sort-order.html

Comment: Yes. Sorry. You are right. I mean Cart Rules for sure. I will check your advise. Thanx again.